# Programatically setting dropdown options in a matrix

Tags: plugin-development, migration, modules

I'm building a Matrix field from within a module's migration.

I can get all fields setup correctly except the options of either a Dropdown or Checkboxes field.

```
$field = new \craft\fields\Matrix([
    'groupId' => 1,
    'name' => $fieldSettings['name'],
    'handle' => $fieldSettings['handle']
])

$blocks = [
    'new1' => [
        'name' => 'Heading',
        'handle' => 'heading',
        'fields' => [
            'new1' => [
                'type' => \craft\fields\Dropdown::class,
                'name' => 'Heading',
                'handle' => 'pageContentHeading',
                'options' => [
                     ['label' => 'H1', 'value' => 'h1', 'default' => 1],
                     ['label' => 'H2', 'value' => 'h2', 'default' => ''],
                     ['label' => 'H3', 'value' => 'h3', 'default' => '']
                 ]
             ]
         ]
     ]
]

$field->setBlockTypes($blocks);

try {
    Craft::$app->getFields()->saveField($field);
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This creates the dropdown field, but doesn't set the options. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! Field-specific options need to go inside 'typesettings'.

```
'typesettings' => [
    'options' => [
        ['label' => 'H1', 'value' => 'h1', 'default' => 1],
        ['label' => 'H2', 'value' => 'h2', 'default' => ''],
        ['label' => 'H3', 'value' => 'h3', 'default' => '']
    ]
]
```